# hibernate one - to - one not mapped

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

These are what the tables in MySQL database look like:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE customer;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+
| customer_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| first_name  | varchar(45)          | NO   |     |
| last_name   | varchar(45)          | NO   |     |
| address_id  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+

mysql> DESCRIBE address;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+
| address_id  | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI |
| address     | varchar(50)          | NO   |     |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+
```

And this is how I am trying to achieve one - to - one relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int customer_id;

    @Basic
    private String first_name;

    @Basic
    private String last_name;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;
```

and in Address.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int address_id;

    @Basic
    private String address;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address", targetEntity = Customer.class)
    private Customer customer;
```

I am testing with a simple test:

```
@Test
public void testGetAll() {
    PersistenceUtil.buildEntityManagerFactory();
    AddressDaoImpl addressDao = new AddressDaoImpl();
    List all = addressDao.getAll();
    System.out.println(all.iterator().next());
}
```

and I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: address is not mapped [FROM address]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the Customer not fetched for an Address entity?

**Edit**

Here is the code for my DAO classes:

```
package biz.tugay.saqila.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 08/08/15 Time: 10:18 */

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    @Override
    public List getAll() {
        EntityManager em = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        List<T> all = em.createQuery("FROM " + getTableName()).getResultList();
        transaction.commit();
        return all;
    }

}

public class AddressDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Address> {
    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return "address";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your getAll() code?

Comment: @wawek I have, I also fixed the question, the test I copied here was wrong.

Comment: @wawek The test failing is: AddressDaoImpl addressDao = new AddressDaoImpl(); not CustomerDaoImpl..

Comment: As @Dragan Bozanovic answered you have to use your class name instead of table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPQL (HQL) class and property names are [case sensitive](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2524). So in your query you must use the proper class name for the `Address` entity:

```
from Address ...
```

So, fix the entity name to start with the uppercase A:

```
public class AddressDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<Address> {
    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return "Address";
    }
}
```